# Length of conveyor path in a conveyor network

Tags: anylogic

I am trying to find the total length of all conveyor paths in my model. While I have been able to figure out the implementation for a specific conveyor path as shown below:

```
for (ConveyorPath cp : conveyorNetwork.paths()) {
    traceln(cp.getName());
    traceln("length in FEET " + cp.length(FOOT));
    traceln("length in FEET " + cp.length(METER));
}
```

I don't know how to implement this if there are multiple conveyor networks in the model. 
I get a Class cannot be resolved to a type when I try the following `ConveyorNetwork cn = getConveyorNetworks();`

Appreciate the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following implementation will let you iterate over multiple conveyor networks in the model and then within it iterate over the conveyor paths.

```
ConveyorNetwork[] cn = getConveyorNetworks();
for (ConveyorNetwork c : cn) {  
    for (ConveyorPath cp : c.paths()) {
        traceln(cp.getName());
        traceln("length in feet " + cp.length(FOOT));
        traceln("length in meters " + cp.length(METER));
    }
}
```